# AsyncTask executes at the end of the function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I am using AsyncTask so that the function I want executes immediately and does not wait till the end to be executed..

but for some reason I don't why it executes in at the end of all process!

I looked at other solutions and found that Thread should be executed at the end but for AsyncTask it should be executed whenever it is called..

here is my code

```
    private void LogMeIn()
 {

        string CheckValue;

        // Here I call the AsyncTask

        new GCM().execute(null,null,null);

        //gcmRegID is a public variable and should has GCM value assigned to it by now, but I it is empty as  GCM() has not been executed yet

           //This is always return empty string
           CheckValue = gcmRegID;
}
```

This is the AsyncTask that wait till the end to be executed

```
//This is the AsyncTask
 private class GCM extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String resp;
        private Context context;



        @Override
        protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {
            GCMHelper  gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper (
                    getApplicationContext());

            try {
                gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister("123456789");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return gcmRegID;
        }


 }
```

I tried to put the call for GCMRegister in onPreExecute but i get an error that it has to be in the main thread

it is like i am going in circles....

the call has to be in the main thread and the main thread will be executed at the end of the function...

it is like no way to get the GCM code in the middle!!!!

How can I make this AsyncTask executes when it called??

Thanks

Comment: It is executed immediately. But you are doing nothing with it. Should take a better look at the documentation.

Comment: "gcmRegID is a public variable and should has GCM value assigned to it by now" - No, it shouldn't, because your task is running asynchronously, which means it doesn't block, and the lines after the `execute()` call proceed immediately.

Comment: Where are you calling `LogMeIn()`?  Try using breakpoints.

Comment: I used breakpoints, it does not go to the AsyncTask !! I have been trying for 3 days with no luck!!..  Mike M. why is it running asynchronously? what i am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code it's hard for me to tell but I would take a look at where you are calling LogMeIn(). Because your AsyncTask and call to execute are nested in the LogMeIn() function, it won't be called until LogMeIn() is first called.

AsyncTask goes through the following 4 steps in order after calling execute():

- onPreExecute()
- doInBackground(Params...)
- onProgressUpdate(Progress...)
- onPostExecute(Result)

These can be added to your GCM class and used however you like. Note that you don't call them directly. AsyncTask does it automatically after calling .execute().

Only the tasks specified in doInBackground(Params...) are executed on a background thread. The rest are all done on the UI(or main) thread. I would suggest putting either a toast or a log inside onPreExecute() and in onPostExecute() to debug where/when GCM().execute is actually being called and then to tell you when the background task is complete. This will give you a better idea of what is going on.

Make sure you aren't trying to update the UI in doInBackground().

Would love to help more but we would need to see more of your code.

```
@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    Log.d("GCM", "onPreExecute: called");
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(String resultOfDoInBackground) {
    super.onPostExecute(resultOfDoInBackground);

    Log.d("GCM", "onPostExecute: called");
}
```

Comment: I tried to put the call for GCMRegister in onPreExecute but i get an error that it has to be in the main thread

it is like i am going in circles....

the call has to be in the main thread and the main thread will be executed at the end of the function...

it is like no way to get the GCM code in the middle!!!!

Comment: Alright, I think I figured out what you are trying to do. You are trying to set the value of gcmRegId to the return value of the AsyncTask's doInBackground, correct?

Comment: I want to get the GCM code and set it in the public variable gcmRegID

Answer (score 1):

**Try this -**

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    new GCM().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,params);
} else { 
    new GCM().execute(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your  new `GCM().execute(null,null,null);` in the protected void `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method. this way it will be called once the app is ran. This way you will have your `GCM` id before you get to the `LogMEIn` method.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask keeps a queue of tasks and a thread pool,the thread pool execute the tasks one by one,so if you have too more tasks ,you will find it not execute your tasks immediately.

And in one process ,all your AsyncTask share one thread pool.In this case,you should make one task queue by yourself,you can just use HandleThread to execute a timely task.